# Nginx query string redirect to another query string?

Tags: nginx

I've been looking for a way to do a redirect om Nginx from an URL with query string to another URL with query string too. I don't know if this is possible, like:

> www.example.com/bol-con-per-11883820001?pid=11883820001&page=1&query=bol+con+per&lang=pt&searchConfigId=58c0312b099ff30013d9df47?utm_source=midway&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=midwaypljan

to

> www.example.com/camp/homeprincipal/jan-18/storePL?utm_source=midway&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=midwaypljan

Any ideas?

Comment: provide more information

Comment: We are trying to do a redirect on Nginx from the first URL to the second one. Any help please?